# Advantage of using individual require in AWS lambda functions

Tags: javascript, performance, lambda, destructuring

Here is my pseudo project:

```
/- utils
     +- func1.js
     +- func2.js
     +- index.js

/- main
     +- index.js
```

In `main/index.js` I can simply require all necessary functions simply like this:

```
const { func1, func2 } = require('../utils');
```

That works okay.

Let's assume there is much more functions - each in individual file and I  only need a few of them.

Is there any advantage/disadvantage of using destructuring?

I mean instead of:

```
const { func1, func2, func5 } = require('../utils');
```

Require each function individually like this:

```
const { func1 } = requrie('../utils/func1');
const { func2 } = requrie('../utils/func2');
const { func5 } = requrie('../utils/func5');
```

The first solution is much cleaner IMHO but can there be a performance issue when there is much more functions? Any other disadvantages like size of deployed lambda?

This is the code used in AWS Lambda functions.

Comment: Size of loaded code usually doesn't matter on typical server environments.

Comment: Size does matter in AWS Lambda. However, with this scenario it's negligible difference.